# Is it possible to set a page fullscreen in silverlight, not to normal?

Tags: c#, silverlight, fullscreen

I am creating a Silverlight application where the user clicks to full screen mode. I want to disable the exit full screen mode option even if he minimizes the screen/not active in that screen. Is there a way for it?

Answer (score 1):

This will prevent the user from Exiting full screen

```
private void Page_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Key == Key.Escape && App.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen)
        {
            App.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried with similar one earlier but it doesn't work. Does it work with navigation page too?

Comment: Where did you use the `keydown` event?

Comment: This is what I tried and it is not working    **XAML**    `<navigation:Page x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.Home" Title="Home Page" KeyDown="Home_KeyDown"> --- </navigation:Page>`    and **C#**    code just the same in the above

Comment: Yeah Its not Working but actually it Exits Full screen when pressing Esc in the fullscreen mode